# how to run redshift automatically

Tags: .desktop, autostart, redshift

I'd like to start redshift application automatically after boot in Ubuntu 16.04.

This can be done by creating a *.desktop file in `.config/autostart`. It leaves me with the terminal window open, though, which is very annoying.

I want to start redshift without an open terminal window. How do I do this?

my redshift.desktop currently looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Redshift
GenericName=Color temperature adjustment
Comment=Color temperature adjustment tool
Exec=redshift &
Icon=redshift
Terminal=true
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `redshift-gtk` which you can set to automatically start when your user logs in.

Run the following commands to install:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install redshift-gtk
```

Search for redshift in your applications and start it up and don't forget to set it to start automatically.

If you are a kde user, you can install `plasma-applet-redshift-control` instead:

```
sudo apt install plasma-applet-redshift-control
```

Comment: @Terrance answer works perfectly. I accepted your answer because I believe it is more useful to others having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Change the line that says `Terminal=true` to `Terminal=false`. It does not need to start within the terminal like that